# How do you concat data in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to send the 4 data tag's value to post, I can't figure out how to concat it though. I also need the data to be one data per line, so a `<br>` in between will suffice.

```
$("#login-1").click(function() {
   send += text($("#" + iconId).data("name"));
   send += text($("#" + iconId).data("login1"));
   send += text($("#" + iconId).data("username1"));
   send += text($("#" + iconId).data("password1"));
   $("#post").text($("#" + iconId).send));
   cancel();
});
```

This is jQuery and I want an easy to read solution, I am learning still.

For example

```
$("#post").text($("#" + iconId).data("name"));
```

This sends the first data, but I can't get the rest to send.

Comment: Is there any error showing?

Comment: `$.post('url', $("#" + iconId).data())`

Comment: Maybe you should try explaining better? It doesn't seem like you're trying to send anything, and "post" is an element, which is all very confusing. Also, the `text()` function is not shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try like this.

```
   $("#login-1").click(function() {
       var send='';
       send += $("#" + iconId).data("name")+"</br>";
       send += $("#" + iconId).data("login1")+"</br>";
       send += $("#" + iconId).data("username1")+"</br>";
       send += $("#" + iconId).data("password1")+"</br>";
       $("#post").html(send);
       cancel();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks goodness, i have been trying to solve that for 4 hours now. I will use this to improve.

Comment: @LèlaNull glad it helped.